# Unable to autoload a php class using psr-4

Tags: php, parse-error, psr-4

I am trying to use psr-4 to autoload a class but the more I try, no results I find. I don't really know how to work with psr-4 and i am so dumb finding how to fix the error. My code structure is as follows:
-project-root
--app
---class
----init.php
--vendor
--index.php
The composer.json code is:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\" : "app/"
    }
}
```

The following is `app/class/init.php`:

```
<?php
namespace App\class;

class Connect
{
    public function connect ()
    {
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

And here is my `index.php` contents:

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use App\class\Connect as connector;

$obj = new connector;
$obj->connect();
```

The code stops running with the following error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) or '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line
>   3
>   Would you please help me to understand where and what my error in writing autoloading related code is? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` is a keyword in PHP. Try to rename directory and respectively name of the namespace (`App\class`) for example to `App\classes`.

Comment: I did what you said and after running composer dump-autoload it now works pretty fine. Thank you very very much and good luck.